# How to combine two layers in Keras? One with embedding, one with "other" feature

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to combine an embedding layer with a numeric feature layer. I did like:

```
tensor_feature = Input(shape=(MAX_LENGTH, 3))
tensor_embed = Input(shape=(MAX_LENGTH, ))
tensor_embed = Embedding(len(word2index), 128)(tensor_embed)

merged_tensor = concatenate([tensor_embed, tensor_feature]) 
model = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True))(merged_tensor)
model = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))(model)
model = TimeDistributed(Dense(len(tag2index)))(model)
model = Activation('softmax')(model)
model = Model(inputs=[tensor_embed,tensor_feature],outputs=model)
```

Noted that `MAX_LENGTH` is 82. 
Unfortunately, I got an error like this:

> **ValueError:** Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor
>   `Tensor("input_2:0", shape=(?, 82), dtype=float32)` at layer "`input_2`".
>   The following previous layers were accessed without issue: `[]`

while combining input and output. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting `tensor_embed` which is an input layer to embedding output and using same again as input in the model.  Change your code to

```
tensor_feature = Input(shape=(MAX_LENGTH, 3))
tensor_embed_feature = Input(shape=(MAX_LENGTH, ))
tensor_embed = Embedding(len(word2index), 128)(tensor_embed_feature)

merged_tensor = concatenate([tensor_embed, tensor_feature]) 
model = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True))(merged_tensor)
model = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))(model)
model = TimeDistributed(Dense(len(tag2index)))(model)
model = Activation('softmax')(model)
model = Model(inputs=[tensor_embed_feature,tensor_feature],outputs=model)
```